# Given a Symfony 2.7 formType object with an added choice field, how can I access the choice strings?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have created a form object in symfony, which is meant to process an api request. It is created in a controller via:

```
$myForm = new MyFormType($foo, $bar);
$form = $this->createForm($myForm, $entity, array('method' => 'POST', 'csrf_protection' => false));
```

Once these objects are created, I pass them into an external service which converts api data into data that's meant to be consumed by the form, like the following:

```
//I pass this in, so that, our api users don't have to pass in 
//{uglyAPIVariable45: 721}, but rather {pretty_variable: "go left"}
$goodData = $this->convertOldData($form->getBuilderDataCopy(), $oldData);
```

One of the things this service does, is if the form has a choice, like a select tag, it attempts to convert any string passed to the api into the value in select tag. This way, if the user can pass over "East" if the select field has the options "North", "West", "South" and "East" associated with the values 0, 4, 5 and 10 and the converter should return 10. The user doesn't have to pass over one of those random values, they can just pass over the string. And if they passed over "Foo", it would return an error along with a description of what good choices they could pass over.

My problem is that, in production, I'm not able to get ahold of those values.

In development, I found that I could get my options using,

```
foreach($formBuilderDataCopy as $formElement){
    $options = $formElement->getAttributes()['data_collector/passed_options']['choices'];
}
```

But when we moved to production, this code broke. The method, getAttributes, returned null suddenly. Admittedly, it seemed kind of janky to begin with, so I wanted to find a more valid approach to getting these choices, possibly even allowing me to bypass a different approach for 'choice', 'entity', 'timezone' et. al.

Unfortunately, looking through the source code and exploring it with get_class_methods and friends hasn't provided me with a solution this issue. Even when I get choices, the most I can get are values, but not the string options in the select box.

What's the appropriate approach to acquiring such information from my symphony forms?

---

As a side note, I have also tried:

```
$form->get('elementName')->getConfig()->getOption('choices');
```

But it also just returns a list of the ids to single numbers and not the strings that replace those numbers. e.g.

```
{3: 0, 5: 1, 10: 2, 11: 3...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an entity Object for the form type. Then you can use the data as object. It must not been a doctrine entity.